# SWT ProgressBar Indeterminate state is showing very slow moving progress bar

Tags: java, progress-bar, swt, eclipse-rap

I tried using Indeterminate state ProgressBar in SWT, using Chrome browser on Ubuntu 11.
Problem here is that ProgressBar is moving too slowly and doesn't looks good.
Is there any way to make the ProgressBar movement faster when it's in Indeterminate state?

Follwing is the code snippet:

```
ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(parent,  SWT.INDETERMINATE);
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this is not possible. The interval is hard-coded in [ProgressBar.js](http://git.eclipse.org/c/rap/org.eclipse.rap.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.rap.rwt/js/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/ProgressBar.js).

You can open an [enhancement request](http://eclipse.org/rap/bugs/) for making this a theming option.